# Using batch file in Jenkins to trigger testng.xml

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, cmd, appium

I am trying to run a batch file from inside my test case to start appium server at a specific port using following code:

```
String cmd="cmd /c \"cd C:\\Program Files\\Appium\\node_modules && start C:\\GitRapo\\MyProject\\samplenote2.bat\"";
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime(); 
    Process pr=r.exec(cmd);
```

samplenote2.bat is a batch file which opens a new instance of cmd prompt and gives the following command:

node appium --address 127.0.0.1 -p 4727
@pause

After this rest of my test case should execute on this appium server. When I manually run testNGBatchFile.bat, I am able to invoke testng.xml, which in turn invokes samplenote2.bat specified in the test case and performs the other operations. But in case of jenkins the testNGBatchFile.bat on execution is able to call testng.xml but unable to call the batch file mentioned in code (i.e. unable to start appium server)

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Its not the problem of jenkin. When you run it manually, I assume that you open that directory and run, which means you are in the same directory.

But the same thing doesn't happen when you run it through code/batch file. You need to navigate the directory in which the file exists.

Try adding **cd** command and mention the respective directory before you execute each file (this includes batch file as well as testNG xml).

For Example :
If you want to run a batch file which is located inside C:\Test\run.bat

Then your first statement inside the batch file should be

```
cd C:\Test
```

Same for testNG file if you are running testNG XML file.

Also, in the java code if you are calling any batch file then first change the directory. It should work.

Comment: Have already done what you are saying. In testNGBatchFile.bat I am setting project location, cd %projectlocation%, setting classpath for bin and lib folders and then I am executing testNG.xml. And for other batch files I have mentioned the code above. Navigating to location first and then calling batch file. When I call  testNGBatchFile.bat in Jenkins, the problem is that its able to invoke testNG.xml but its not able to open a new cmd prompt to start the "samplenote2.bat" due to which my test is getting skipped. I am able to print in console some message before executing cmd section code.

Comment: PFB link for entire code. 
https://github.com/amritkrishan/Appium/tree/master/MyProject